# HTML5/JS How to show DatePicker onload (no libraries )

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I try to show the datepicker popup (input type="date") immediately after the HTML content has loaded. But in my example below, I get only the alert-message. Clicking the ok-button afterwards shows the alert-message and the datepicker. Is this a timing problem? How can I solve this?

Could only test this with Chrome on Android so far. Finally I want to use this with the Android-App Tasker. There you can show scenes (Dialogs) with HTML content. I would prefer a solution without libraries like jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body onload="clickPicker()">
    <p>Select date:</p>
    <input type="date" id="picker">
    <button id="ok" onclick="clickPicker()">OK</button>
    <script>
      function clickPicker()
      {
        alert("clickPicker");
        document.getElementById("picker").click();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I run the snippet the function is called like it should do. But I think it's not possible to display the datepicker onload. I think you will need a library.

Comment: @gillesc: But it shows alert("clickPicker") onload. So the function is called correctly. Anyway, putting it above does not change the behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new here: Is it good practice to delete a comment (even if it is not correct) when someone else referred already to this comment?

Comment: Only delete if you fully failed your comment and you don't want to edit it to something better. It's not bad when more than one is pointing at something. You also can edit and additionally refer to someone like "_like XXX said, this and that...._"

Comment: It is also not possible to define the display format of the input field. So I think I will have a look at jquery or something similar. Thx, Cagatay Ulubay.